# Record video with face filter

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, face-detection, video-recording

From the last two weeks, I'm struggling with building real-time face filter application which can also record videos but sadly I'm not successful yet. Currently, I'm using ` for rendering real-time face position.
I wanna record that rectangle view too while recording. Please let me know if someone has done this kind of work.

Well, I'm able to detect faces in real-time using `android.media.FaceDetector` class but the problem is with recording. For rending the face positions I'm using `SurfaceView` where in `surfaceChanged` method I prepared my camera resource and save frame in the video file but due to these multiple tasks at the same time application lacks and only video recording is working.

This is my code:

```
   @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // We have no surface, return immediately:
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }


//        if (!button.isChecked()) {

        mCamera.stopPreview();

        configureCamera(width, height);
        setDisplayOrientation();
        setErrorCallback();

        // Create media.FaceDetector
        float aspect = (float) previewHeight / (float) previewWidth;
        fdet = new android.media.FaceDetector(prevSettingWidth, (int) (prevSettingWidth * aspect), MAX_FACE);


        // Everything is configured! Finally start the camera preview again:
        startPreview();

//        }



        if (isRecording)
            prepareRecorder(mView.getHolder());

    }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after weeks, I find official google `sceneform-android-sdk` for handling 3D models while recording videos.You can download working example from [Github](https://github.com/beNitinhere/video-recording-with-face-filters.git).

For more information about ArCore checkout the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/video-recording)

:)

Comment: Was this is the final best strategy to do it? Could you please share code example for it, would really save me weeks, thank you.